# How to include values from object inside <label> html tag in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I need to include value from object which comes from controller via ViewBag inside the `<label>` and `<input>` html tag. The following is which I used inside the view page:

```
foreach (var stockItem in ViewBag.joinqry2)
{
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <label style='font-weight:normal;' name='InstockID' value= 'stockItem.ItemName' ><span> @(stockItem.ItemName) </span></label>
          <input class='form-control input_field stockItem' name='labOrder.ConsumedInventories[ + i + ].ConsumedQuantity' type='number' id='" + data[i].Instock + "' min='0' value= '"+ stockItem.ConsumedQuantity + "'/>
     </div>
}
```

ViewBag.joinqry2:

```
{ ConsumedQuantity = 1, ItemName = "Streck Tube" }
{ ConsumedQuantity = 1, ItemName = "Bubble Wrap" }
{ ConsumedQuantity = 7000, ItemName = "Biohazard Bag" }
{ ConsumedQuantity = 1, ItemName = "Absorbent Papers" } 
{ ConsumedQuantity = 1, ItemName = "Test Tube" }
```

StockItem contains ConsumedQuantity and ItemName values inside the foreach loop but I am still getting error like this below:

My error is:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   App_Web_euru3gao.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for
>   'ItemName'

Comment: Check your ViewBag is properly filled or not

Comment: @BharatPatidar .. yes it is filled correctly ... I even checked inside the foreach and each stockItem carries individual ItemName and ConsumedQuantity data

Comment: Just as an FYI this is considered bad practice.. you need to create a strongly-typed ViewModel for this.  It will assist in maintaining the code later down the line and is generally cleaner... but anyway... what is the class name that holds the properties `ConsumedQuantity` and `ItemName`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid... thanks for the info.. I try your method... and ViewBag.joinqry2 is generated from the joining two tables.. that is ConsumedQuantity and ItemName are from two different tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the item retrieved from the ViewBag. In your current implementation, stockItem is an `object`, therefore it does not contain a property ItemName.

As BviLLe_Kid mentioned, the cleaner way is to use a ViewModel:

```
public class ConsumedItemModel {
    public int ConsumedQuantity {get; set;}
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
}
```

In your cshtml file, use the `@model` directive to tell Razor which ViewModel to expect. If you need additional properties, create a ViewModel that also contains the collection of `ConsumedItemModel` as a property. The following assumes that you only pass the collection of `ConsumedItemModel` from the controller.

```
@model IList<ConsumedItemModel>
foreach (var stockItem in Model) {
    var name = stockItem.ItemName;
    var qty = stockItem.ConsumedQuantity;
    // render label and input
}
```